# Ceph Manual Deployment no ceph -s output after mon installs (Nautilus)

Tags: ceph

I'm trying to build a cluster to test stuff before i apply them to out production cluster. We're using Ceph Nautilus so i decided to install Nautilus first as well.
Used the docs below:
https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/install/manual-deployment/
Everything seemed to go fine. I installed 3 monitors, generated the monmap copied keyrings to other monitors, started services and they are all up. But when i type ceph -s to check the cluster status it just gets stuck forever without any output. Any command that uses the word "ceph" in it just gets stuck. As a result i can't continue to build the cluster since i need to be able to use ceph commands after monitor deployments to install other services.
Systemctl outputs are the same for all 3 monitors in the current state:

```
[root@mon2 ~]# systemctl status ceph-mon@mon2
● ceph-mon@mon2.service - Ceph cluster monitor daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ceph-mon@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-04-28 09:55:24 +03; 25min ago
 Main PID: 4725 (ceph-mon)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-ceph\x2dmon.slice/ceph-mon@mon2.service
           └─4725 /usr/bin/ceph-mon -f --cluster ceph --id mon2 --setuser ceph --setgroup ceph

Apr 28 09:55:24 mon2 systemd[1]: Started Ceph cluster monitor daemon.
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs that the cluster is actually in "HEALTH_OK" status? Do you have ceph.conf readable on all nodes? Are the directorie permissions correct under `/var/lib/ceph/`? Do all mon hosts time out with a ceph command? I assume you already tried restarting the mon services?

Comment: Answering by order or your questions:
No, Yes, Yes, Yes and Yes.
Resolved this issue btw, seems i forgot firewalld and selinux configurations before installation. After configuring those the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, the problem is caused by missing firewalld and selinux configurations. After applying those and restarting the deployment process my issue was solved.